# Matlab profile viewer formatting

Tags: matlab, profiling

Is there any syntax in matlab where i can see the result from the profiler in a slighlty different format? In particular I would like to see instead of total time spent, let's in a particular function, the fraction from total time that is spent there.

So, for example

Instead of

function_name 300s,

i would like to have

function_name 10%

and so on.

**UPDATE**

As a clarification I want this formatting type to apply in the "Summary profile" page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of typing the command you use to run your program put that command in a file called start.m (for example), now type `profile viewer` in the command line and run `start` to profile.

You can click the function, in my case called main, and then select the 'show child function' check box and press refresh.

Now you have an overview with percentages :)

Good luck!

[image: Profiler]

Comment: Thanks. I can see this BUT the summary profile page does not come up with the same format in percentages, which basically I am more interested in. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The summary does not provide percentages. Therefore you put your program in a .m file, so that you can treat your program as a function and use the detailed report as the summary.